# Measure Position of Electron Directly

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, experimental-physics, measurements, quantum-measurements

What is the most directly way to measure the position of free electron in an expirement?
I don't asking about theoretical suggestion but rather on practical expirement which people have done.

Answer (score 1):

As far  as I know, you only know the location an electron is when it interacts with something else.  If you know where the other thing was, then you know where the electron was.  The other thing might be the the element in a charge coupled device, an ionize gas molecule in a cathode ray tube, a droplet in a cloud chamber, or an ion on a photographic plate.